# How to correctly type a function that receives an object with multiple key:value pairs?

Tags: typescript

I have an object that has some user session values in it:

```
const userSession = {
  token: '',
  full_name: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  role_name: '',
  gender: '',
}
```

and i have a function that has to update one or more values in this object, but i struggle how to specify type of object that has unknown number of values. Feels like it has to be done with generics, but i don't have much experience with them.
For example if called

```
updateSession({token: 'some new token value', gender: 'new gender'})
should return {
  token: 'some new token value',
  full_name: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  role_name: '',
  gender: 'new gender',
}
```

What i've tried:

```
const updateSession = <T extends {}>(objectParam: T) => {
  const updatedUserObject = { ...userSession }
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objectParam)) {
    console.log(`${key} ${value}`)
    updatedUserObject[key] = value
  }
  return updatedUserObject
}
```

But that doesn't have much sense at all...

Using @obe's solution now gives me `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'UserSessionInterface'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'UserSessionInterface'`
where my function and interface are:

```
export interface UserSessionInterface {
  token: string
  email?: string
  full_name?: string
  username?: string
  password?: string
  role_name?: string
  gender?: string
  imageUri?: string
}

const session: UserSessionInterface = {
  token: '',
  full_name: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  role_name: '',
  gender: '',
}

const updateSession = (objectWithUpdates: UserSessionInterface) => {
      const updatedUserObject: UserSessionInterface = { ...session }
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objectWithUpdates)) {
        console.log(`${key} ${value}`)
        updatedUserObject[key] = value
      }
      try {
        await EncryptedStorage.setItem(
          'user_session',
          JSON.stringify(updatedUserObject),
        )
        console.log('successfully updated data')
        console.log(updatedUserObject)
        setSession(updatedUserObject)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    }
```

Which i've fixed as `updatedUserObject[key as keyof IEmptySession] = value`, so i wonder now, is this a valid fix or is there a better way? A [TSPlayground with that error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEC2AHMBPAZQgGdjgB7EZAbwChlkxyBrCEALmWLClAHMANPWQwArgBtxAfRBxMEAPyduvEIOGji0WfKVce-IQ2xxSAd3JQAJnpWHhUcuIgy5i5QbVHkfNlei2nuoAvrS0APThyKCQsIgoGDj4RKQUVHSRDAwA2qD+AB4eqnwAukX8ANwRUaG0CJTcyBBJhCRklJyJuK2plAwAvDTCTKwcyADk495ikq7ynJPemtpuC1PCJuaWVmvejs5zELvCviD+UMe19SCNothWcJAp7VSDABTkAEYAVhAIYAAFOBQOSdLDdZ5pACUYJakL6-QAfEMGNdbvdHhArABVLRQADyPz+YFhELaaWQg2oyAAdHTmmTelRQgwYJZkG80WBkNlWHgBMgAG5wcSiCAlZDkGDIQm-f40tgGEgfIn-IEgzBQqEorJopwQGnich8N4AAwAJNQ+cFkJbhaKIMFTVDhKiGvrDca3rLiQrwLxlV85YDgXIta7kHrnJ6TfhsBApcg+S6ssg7g9IDi8T7-ryIHgJYN7WLkJEADxlgC01ZryCgEGw4niSfzyDMwDAAAtOHzkKYW3hE11kuTKMIWXWIGBRFAqOnMVnoDmwLRQlGDUaTfOnqOQG9qCM2AtTFYpmm8TojhMT+NglqgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the object as an interface with (some?) optional keys:

```
interface IEmptySession {
  token: string,
  full_name?: string,
  username?: string,
  password?: string,
  role_name?: string,
  gender: string,
}

...

const updateSession = (objectParam: IEmptySession): IEmptySession => {
  const updatedUserObject: IEmptySession = { ...objectParam }
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objectParam)) {
    console.log(`${key} ${value}`)
    updatedUserObject[key] = value
  }
  return updatedUserObject
}
```

If you want to allow any key then you can define the interface like this:

```
interface IEmptySession {
   [index: string]: string;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i like the first approach, but now i have a 
```updatedUserObject[key] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SessionInterface'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'SessionInterface'.``` warning, i fixed it with ```updatedUserObject[key as keyof SessionInterface] = value```, is it good approach or it is a 'bad' fix?

Comment: i see. well, it's not an answer to your question, but maybe you can explain why you need the `for` loop? why isn't `const updatedUserObject: IEmptySession = { ...objectParam }` enough?

Comment: As specified in question and playground, ```updatedUserObject``` is a copy of an external variable that should be returned as update one with values from ```objectParam```. Maybe there was a lack of explanation, sorry.

Comment: Ok, but in the code you provided this is not what happens, right? It's a little confusing... but anyway how about writing it like `const updatedUserObject: IEmptySession = { ...externalObject, ...objectParam }`? Anyway if I'm still don't understand your intention then maybe you can update the posted code to accurately represent what you're doing...

Comment: I've updated my code, which should do the following: given an external object that has some user session info in it, should be updated with a function that could have multiple parameters, so i can update from 1 to n fields of this user object. I had this logic: i can pass multiple parameters that can be spread into updatedUserObject and then i iterate over my input objectWithUpdates parameters, and i overwrite properties in my updatedUserObject which is then set to storage and state etc... And that's what happens in code i provided. Does just spreading 2 objects into 1 with overwriting?

Comment: If yes that's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Yes, when spreading multiple objects, the right-hand objects overwrite the left-hand objects (by keys)

Comment: Yeah... Thanks! Could be made much easier with your suggestion.

Comment: ( `{ ...{ a: 42, b: 666 }, ...{ b: 88 } }` yields `{ a: 42, b: 88 }` )

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted!